# Textarea readonly but change background color back to white

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a textarea readonly but do not like the gray background and want to make it white again... Is this possible because everything I am trying fails and it stays gray.

http://jsfiddle.net/ma42koz3/

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="row">
                  <div id="DToday" class="col-xs-12">
                      <label class="centered" for="DueToday">DUE TODAY @ 5:00</label>
                      <textarea type="text" name="DueToday" id="DueToday" class="form-control" rows="7"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div id="DTmrw" class="col-xs-12">
                      <label class="centered" for="DueTmrw">DUE <span id="delivery-date"></span> @ 5:00</label>
                      <textarea type="text" name="DueTmrw" id="DueTmrw" class="form-control" rows="7"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#DueToday').attr('readonly', true);
    $('#DueToday').addClass('input-disabled');
    $('#DueTmrw').attr('readonly', true);
    $('#DueTmrw').addClass('input-disabled');

});
```

CSS

```
.input-disabled{
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `!important` in your rule in order to override the browsers default  value:

```
.input-disabled{
    background-color:#FFF !important;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ma42koz3/1/)

Answer (score 7):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/ma42koz3/2/

CSS

```
.form-control[disabled], .form-control[readonly], fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
   background-color: white;
}
```

EDIT:

You can add class for example `no-gray`on textarea you don't want to be gray http://jsfiddle.net/ma42koz3/4/
and use this

CSS

```
.form-control[readonly].no-gray {
  background-color:white;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea type="text" name="DueToday" id="DueToday" class="form-control no-gray" rows="7"></textarea>
```

Comment: How did you separate those textareas that you want grayed?

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
<textarea style= "background-color: white" type="text" name="DueToday" id="DueToday" class="form-control" rows="7">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's .css function instead of a class:

```
$('#DueToday').css("background-color", "#ff00ff");
```

[Modified JsFiddle (Original by taxicala)](http://jsfiddle.net/ma42koz3/6/)